# Pythonic: How much work is too much work to run at the time of file import

Tags: python, enums

Conceptually what I'm wanting to do is below. I have an enum for status, and I want to make a set which defines the statuses which are a 'completed' status (e.g. finished and failed)

My internal gripe is that the variable 'completed_statuses' is being created at import time.  I've been on teams where people would make REST endpoint calls at the time of import and it's caused large issues, so I'm so I'm somewhat gunshy on the topic. It's my understanding that it's non-pythonic to 'do work' at the time of import. I'm not sure how else to do it other than maybe making a class with static methods. That seems overboard to me though.

Is below the most pythonic way of doing it? Is there a better way?

```py
from enum import Enum, auto

class Status(Enum):
    PENDING = auto()
    FINISHED = auto()
    FAILED = auto()

completed_statuses = set((Status.FINISHED, Status.FAILED))
```

Comment: This should be fine. Defining a set isn't going to take considerably longer than defining `Status` in the first place. I'd say, as long as you aren't doing I/O of any kind or working with *large* amounts of static data, you're fine.

Comment: I agree with @chepner but one more thing. How is this class being used? Why couldn't you just put the `completed_statuses` in a separate file?

Comment: @catasaurus That's a fair point. Defining in the scope I need it would be fine for what I'm doing right now. I've been on projects before where numerous things needed to understand status, so having 'completed' was useful, but as I think of it, those programs were more monolithic than micro, so maybe I'm just biased to thinking I need it when I don't